# Executing python scripts in azure data bricks and azure data factory

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I'm trying to execute a python script in azure databricks cluster from azure data factory.

Python activity reads `main.py` from `dbfs:/scripts/main.py`
This main script is importing another class from `dbfs:/scripts/solutions.py`

```
#main.py
import solutions

print ("hello")
```

While running in ADB, only main.py is copied from dbfs to execut and thowing error that solutions not found.

How can i execute this in ADF?

thanks